# Evaluating $\sum \limits_{i=1}^{\infty} i^2 \exp\left[- \frac{(i+1/2)^2}{2s^2}\right] , \ s>0 $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

How can we evaluate the following sum.

$$
\sum \limits_{i=1}^{\infty} i^2 \exp\left[- \frac{(i+1/2)^2}{2s^2}\right] , \quad s>0 
$$